# how to return activity based on timedate mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

this is my fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5422fb347abaf2bde082eb522f5be4fb

```
table data2
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------+----------+
|               user_id                | event_timestamp |   event_name   | level_id |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------+----------+
| 895A8F53-C61C-471A-B934-CC2795286E19 | 2020-01-01      | level_complete |        1 |
| 895A8F53-C61C-471A-B934-CC2795286E19 | 2020-01-02      | level_complete |        2 |
| 895A8F53-C61C-471A-B934-CC2795286E19 | 2020-01-02      | level_complete |        3 |
| 895A8F53-C61C-471A-B934-CC2795286E19 | 2020-01-02      | level_complete |        4 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------+----------+

table data3
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+------------+----------+
|               user_id                | event_timestamp | event_name | level_id |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+------------+----------+
| 895A8F53-C61C-471A-B934-CC2795286E19 | 2019-12-31      | level_end  |        1 |
| 895A8F53-C61C-471A-B934-CC2795286E19 | 2020-01-01      | level_end  |        2 |
| 895A8F53-C61C-471A-B934-CC2795286E19 | 2020-01-01      | level_end  |        3 |
| 895A8F53-C61C-471A-B934-CC2795286E19 | 2020-01-01      | level_end  |        4 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+------------+----------+
```

so i have 2 tables, if user_id has completed the level, then that data come to data2 table, but if failed the level, then the data come to data3 table. so i want to order by the event_timestamp so the expected results was like this

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+
|               user_id                | event_timestamp |    event_name    | level_id |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+
| 895A8F53-C61C-471A-B934-CC2795286E19 | 2019-12-31      | level_end        |        1 |
|                                      | 2020-01-01      | level_completed  |        1 |
|                                      | 2020-01-01      | level_end        |        2 |
|                                      | 2020-01-01      | level_end        |        3 |
|                                      | 2020-01-01      | level_end        |        4 |
|                                      | 2020-01-02      | level_compeleted |        2 |
|                                      | 2020-01-02      | level_completed  |        3 |
|                                      | 2020-01-02      | level_completed  |        4 |                                                   
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+
```

i've tried with this query

```
select * from data2
inner join data3 on data2.user_id = data3.user_id
order by data2.event_timestamp, data3.event_timestamp;
```

but the output was not like i expected

Comment: Not join.. maybe using `UNION`?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=20f828f5b99e54e2acd56cd8b4c3de0c it become like this

Comment: The structure does not provide integrity check (i.e. `level1>level2` does not guarantee `date1`>=`date2` in any table, and `data2.level=data3.level` does not guarantee `data2.date>=date3.date`). What output do you need if these conditions are false? PS. The tables stores the same entity, and only one attribute differs, it seems. Why two tables are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select * from data2 union
select * from data3
order by event_timestamp, level_id;
```

Using `UNION` and order by event_timestamp, level_id;

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=03b02e0d079011aa4f9e3af7974a98f1

Comment: this was true, but almost true, can i make it into just like my expected results? because in my real case, there's a lot of user_id

Comment: i've tried with this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7ea8662ddf5060a5c66416477fa29ec5

Comment: The error you specify is because of `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` setting. Is your real database setting using it (the sql_mode)? This is how you quickly resolve the `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` issue in any fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cc36879bdf7de09be16560ba29c752a2

Comment: Your expected result means on the left side of `user_id` it only show once?

Comment: I can think of a way but only if you're using MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB 10.3 and above ... something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e294f9ca792fea07171c7a41f9f2dd4

Comment: @FachryDzaky *yes it only show once for every user_id* Do it (replace `user_id` with empty string if the value in previous row is the same) on the client side.